# Smallest number of cash to be given upon a purchase

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I came across a question recently as follows:-

So a program must accept a number and then it tell the least number of coins, notes and cents to be returned from that number.

notes can be 25,50,100,200
coins can be 1,5,20
cents can be 5,20,50

say you input 290, it should return (200 * 1) , (50 * 1), (20 * 2)

It should have been done in matlab, but that but not a constraints, i just want to have an idea about how to proceed, i've been able to get the amount but its not the least number of notes, coins or cents.

```
function y = functest(purchase)
purchase = 500 - purchase;
values = [200,100,50,25,20,5,1,0.5,0.2,0.05];
data = ['note','note''note','note','coin','coin','coin','cent','cent','cent'];
returnval = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
position=1;
    while( position <= length(values) )       
         if purchase - values(position) > 0
             returnval(position) = returnval(position) +1;
             purchase = purchase - values(position);
         else
             position = position + 1;
         end
    end
    allOneString = sprintf('%.0f,' , returnval);
    allOneString = allOneString(1:end-1);% strip final comma
     fprintf('value of a: %s\n', allOneString);
end
```

Comment: I think you want to use your `purchase` and divide it by each element of `values` and use the `floor` function to truncate the remainder; and use the remainder and divide it by the next value (you can loop through this if you want). In the end you will have the minimum number of Notes/Coin that make up purchase.

Comment: Type "coin change" or "change giving" in the search box; you'll find dozens of questions about this problem. It even has its own tag `coin-change`.

Answer (score 0):

I think something simple like this should give you the right answer?

```
data = {'note','note''note','note','coin','coin','coin','cent','cent','cent'};
purchase = 500 - purchase;
values = [200,100,50,25,20,5,1,0.5,0.2,0.05];
remainder = purchase;
for t = 1:size(values,2)
   res(t) = floor(remainder / values(t));
   remainder = remainder - res(t)*values(t);
end
notenumber = res(find(res>0));
notesize = values(find(res>0));
notetype = data(find(res>0));
for g = 1:size(find(res>0),2)
   sprintf('%.0f, %.0f, %s' , notenumber(g), notesize(g), char(notetype(g)));
end


>>
   '2, 200, note'    '1, 50, note'    '1, 5, coin'
```

Comment: Got your point, but say i enter 290, i will get 1*200,1*50,1*25,3*5, which is not correct as i can get 1*200,1*50,2*20 which is more optimized

Answer (score 0):

You've got the array muddling you.   This is a test largely of analysis.

You have three categories of denomination.  They are "Notes", "Coins", "Cents".

Since none of these hold identical values within them, we can use division and store the remainder.  I won't give you the exact code, but I will give you an example as PC and I think you'll see what I mean.

```
Given = 590.53

double remainder = 0
note200 = Floor(Given / 200) //2
remainder = Given % 200 //remainder of 190.53
note100 = Floor(remainder / 100) //1
remainder = remainder % 100 //90.53
etc etc etc.
```

This is also a great example for recursion if you plan it properly. This would let you run a loop through your existing arrays to match the data up. 
public string calcFunction(denomValue, amount)

Eventually, you'd end up with 2 200's, 1 100, 1 50, 1 25, 4 5-coins, 1 0.5 cent, and if they existed 3 0.1 cents but I dont' see that in your list.

Answer (score 0):

This is harder that it first looks. I have an idea how this could work:

Start with the smallest cent and calculate devide the returnvalue by them:

In your example: `290 -> (5800*0.05)`

Then combine them always to the next higher value, so you have no reminder:

```
(5800*0.05) -> (1450*0.20) -> (580*0.50) -> ... -> (58*5) -> (14*20) + (2*5) -> ... ->
```

That would be your solution
    (1*200) + (4*20) + (2*5)

At least you have to try to find combinations of the remainings (I am aware, that this will be a bit complicated to implement): `(2*20)+(2*5) -> (1*50)`

```
(1*200) + (4*20) + (2*5) -> (1*200) + (1*50) + (2*20)
```

Comment: Just start with the largest value instead of the smallest and the whole problem becomes pretty straight forward.

Comment: My answer must be 1*200, 1*50, 2*20